# angular ui routes state duplication due to multiple urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs with angular ui routes and I have a problem with multiple urls for route.
I have a state called "bookDetails". Book have unique id and unique name and therefore can be accessed both using id or name:

```
/books/:bookName
/books/id/:bookId
```

Those two routes are actually the same state. But I can't use the same state for multiple routes. Therefore I have to split it to two states:

```
$stateProvider.state('booByName', {
                    url: '/books/:bookName',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/book-details.html',
                    controller: bookController
                })
                .state('bookById', {
                    url: '/books/id/:bookId',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/book-details.html',
                    controller: bookController
                });
```

Although I have code duplication, I can tolerate this. The problem begins when I have another view related to book: bookReaders. bookReaders shows the user all the user that read this book.
The ideal thing is to have "bookDetails" state and "bookDetails.bookReaders" substate. But because I have multiple routes for book, I have to create another two states:
`bookByName.bookReaders` and `bookById.bookReaders` and duplicate the states as well.

What is the best practice for such thing? How can I prevent states duplication?

Comment: I like your question. Any success finding a solution? Maybe [this post](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/293) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UI Router? If so, you can use $urlMatcherFactory and UrlMatchers instead of writing the absolute URL. Then, define one state and a matcher that will match on both ID and Name, setting the state params accordingly.